# WebBrowser control in UWP (Windows 10) XAML

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

Can you tell me how can I provide a browser control in Windows 10 (WUP) XAML?
When I'm using WebControl I'm getting a compile error that says

> WebBrowser is not supported in a Windows Universal project.

I have to show an "external" website, not a static HTML resource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Universal Windows apps in Xaml use the [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) to display HTML content.

Xaml:

```
<WebView Source="http://stackoverflow.com" />
```

From code:

```
 myWebView.Source = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I forgot to mention that I have to show a web page from the internet, not an "internal" HTML resource.

Comment: That doesn't change the answer. You'll use the WebView for both local and remote HTML pages

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT Does WebView support cookie like WebBrowser does?

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences ,others then above you can go Package.app manifest changes the start page to the URL that you want .